# Prefill iphone calendar event via hyperlink

Tags: java, iphone, ios, url-scheme

I want to prefill iPhone calendar by clicking a hyperlink on my website.

What is the syntax for the URL scheme to pass event data to calendar app?

I want this in a way, so that by clicking the link an event is created with 'this text' as event name and 'description' as the description.

I tried it with `x-apple-reminder://` but it only opens the reminder app.

How to prefill the event data?

Comment: You mean you have a web site and you want to create an Event from your website to reflect on your device?

Comment: yes @Deepesh I have a website and a link 'Add to reminder'. This link should open native Iphone reminder/calendar app and populate an event with some text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access and send some data as parameter to your application via safari then you should try this article

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

It explains url schemes under `Optionally Handle the URL`

```
myapp://

myapp://some/path/here

myapp://?foo=1&amp;bar=2

myapp://some/path/here?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Deepesh, I use `href=x-apple-reminder://` in <a> tag,but I also want to send reminder name and description with this URL. I dont know the parameters to be used for the reminder app. I wld be thankful if you can help me this.

Comment: @user2369800: You can pass the reminder name and description in simple parameters and fetch them in your app, once you have both the params you can add them as an event. Here is another example in details which might help you http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your fast replies @Deepesh.I need the iphone native reminder app to set an event with the name and description. I have a website in JAVA, from there i will pass the name and description. So which parameters does x-apple-reminder:// use? I dont want to develop another iphone app.